# Вылетает Android приложение: Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: android-sdk, android, listview, java, eclipse

Приложение вылетает при данном моменте кода.

```
public void onNewDay(View v){
setContentView(R.layout.day);
String[] items = { "Hello", "world" };
ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.menu_item,items);
menuList.setAdapter(adapt);
}
```

Полный код

```
package com.ruskol.tnote;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView menuList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        menuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public void onExit(View v){
        this.finish();
    }

    public void onStart(View v){
        setContentView(R.layout.days);
    }

    public void onSettings(View v){
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    }

    public void onNewDay(View v){
        setContentView(R.layout.day);
        String[] items = { "Hello", "world" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.menu_item, items);
        menuList.setAdapter(adapt);
    }
}
```

Лог:

> `11-18 17:42:42.276: D/AndroidRuntime(333): Shutting down VM
> 11-18 17:42:42.276: W/dalvikvm(333): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
> 11-18 17:42:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 11-18 17:42:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(333): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
> 11-18 17:42:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
> 11-18 17:42:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
> 11-18 17:42:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
> 11-18 17:42:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
> 11-18 17:42:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
> 11-18 17:42:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
> 11-18 17:42:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
> 11-18 17:42:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 11-18 17:42:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
> 11-18 17:42:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
> 11-18 17:42:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
> 11-18 17:42:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> 11-18 17:42:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(333): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> 11-18 17:42:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 11-18 17:42:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
> 11-18 17:42:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
> 11-18 17:42:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  ... 11 more
> 11-18 17:42:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(333): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> 11-18 17:42:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.ruskol.tnote.MainActivity.onNewDay(MainActivity.java:53)
> 11-18 17:42:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  ... 14 more`

Comment: Лог ошибки киньте.

Comment: Добавил лог.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Ошибка в 53-ей строке, что то там у вас пустое(NullPointerException) и поэтому ошибка. И если я правильно понял то ошибка в методе onClick.
Выложите полный код класса MainActivity и может мы вам, чем то поможем.

Comment: Выложил полный код.

Comment: А каким образом происходит onNewDay?

Comment: наерно на новом view нету menuList

Comment: Вот так

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="@string/New_day"
        android:onClick="onNewDay"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:width="200dp" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gorets, вы были правы, спасибо большое за ответ. Проблема решилась переносом

```
menuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

на событие перехода к новому layout.

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте. Вам скорее всего нужно добавить на форму `day` ваш `ListView`, и инициализировать его (`ListView`) ещё раз.

```
   public void onNewDay(View v){
            setContentView(R.layout.day);
            String[] items = { "Hello", "world" };
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.menu_item, items);
            menuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1_day);//ListView который находится на форме day.
            menuList.setAdapter(adapt);
        }
```